# how do i print elements of vector of pair?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std-pair

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> v;
    v.push_back({10,20});

    // This works
    std::cout << v[0].first << " " << v[0].second << "\n";

    // But I'd like to just be able to do
    std::cout << v[0] << "\n";
}
```

How can we print a vector of `pair`s instead of printing separate values of the `pair`s like `v[i].first` and `v[i].second`? I want to print like `cout << v[i];` but it shows an error.

Comment: Because `pair` could be expanded around types that can't be printed and because there will be no universal agreement on what `<<` should look like for a `pair`, `pair` does not have a `<<`. That said, you can write your own. `std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & out, std::pair<int,int> val) { code for required formatting goes here }`

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) and [Why using namespace std is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).

Comment: And you could go a step further and write `std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & out, std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> val)`

Comment: @user4581301 should be passing the `vector` by const reference instead: `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>& val)` instead

Comment: Whoop. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

`std::pair` does not have a defined `operator<<`. Therefore, you have to define it yourself.

You can use this template to print any `std::pair<T, Y>` you want, as long as `T` and `Y` have defined `operator<<` as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename Y>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& stream, std::pair<T,Y> const& p) -> std::ostream& {
    stream << p.first << ' ' << p.second;
    return stream;
}

auto main() -> int {
    std::pair<int,int> p{1, 2};
    std::cout << p << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `template<typename T, typename Y>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::pair<T,Y>>& pair) -> std::ostream&
{
    for(const auto& el : pair)
        os << el.first << ' ' << el.second << '\n';
    return os;
}`